# How can i neatly format my spider CSV export?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, formatting, web-crawler

I am trying to export my scraped results into a CSV file but the export is off..

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'company'
start_urls = ['https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/Company/Find?q=a']

def parse(self, response):


# this gets the entire block
for i in response.css('div.search_result_title'):
  #print ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text').extract() if j.strip()])
  yield {'Company name': ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text').extract() if j.strip()])}

  for i in response.css('div.searchAddress'):
    #print ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text').extract() if j.strip()])
    yield {'Adress': ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text\n').extract() if j.strip()])}
```

The export shows one company name, followed with 20 (all the other addresses). Then the next company name, followed with he same addresses..

I dont see whats wrong, i hope anyone sees why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format do you need? You have blocks with information, you can make dictionary with all the data and then yield it.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for i in response.css('div.searchResult'):
        yield {
            'company_name': i.css('div.search_result_title a::text').get(),
            'address': i.css('div.searchAddress::text').get(),
        }
```

What exactly do you want?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. I will do take some courses in python, I took python a year a go, completely forgot about dictionaries. I appreciate it thank you!